# How to add a file as attachment in Spring integraion Webservices outbound gateway

Tags: attachment, spring-integration

I have a spring integration outbound gateway for Webservices. Till this time, i send the request in xml format to the web services.
Now, I need to send a file as part of the request to the web service.
How will I do that?
 Below is the spring integration chain existing configuration:

```
<!--  Chain to Process requests for XXXXX-->
    <int:chain id="psTestChain" input-channel="psTestInputChannel" >
        <!-- Set up transformer for input message -->
        <int:transformer method="transform"  ref="testRequestXformer"/>

        <!-- This Spring Integration chain first adds the service name and the 
            service operation headers to the Spring Integration message using the header 
    <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="#{XXXXXXXXX}"
                value="TestSearch" />
            <int:header
                name="#{XXXXXX}"
                value="searchByTestIdentifier" />
        </int:header-enricher>

        <!-- The WS outbound gateway is used to make an outgoing SOAP call. -->
        <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="simpleGateway"
            destination-provider="testDestinationProvider"
            message-sender="testHttpsMessageSender"
            interceptor="test_wss4jInterceptor"
            header-mapper="testSoapHeaderMapper"/>

        <!-- Set up transformer for output message -->
        <int:transformer method="transform" ref="testResponseXformer"/> 

    </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look, please, to the [MTOM sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws-samples/tree/master/mtom) for the Spring WS project.

Since Spring Integration WS module is fully based on the Spring WS, I think there won't be so mutch difference to build JaxB object with attachements as Message `payload` and send it to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>` with `marshaller` injection.

We have an open [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1800) on the matter, but I don't have enough time to see what we should do there.

I've just raised an [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INTSAMPLES-140) for Spring Integration Samples to track the ability of MTOM in Spring Integration.